# TB Mega Menus: Image block doesn't show anything

Tags: blocks, navigation

I'm building my first page with Drupal, creating a subthem of Omega 4, and for the menus I chose to use TB Mega Menu. The problem is that I want one of the columns of the drop down to contain an image. For that, I create a block and add that image to it, having it this HTML code:

```
<p><img alt="" src="http://localhost:81/www.mysite.com/sites/all/themes/mytheme/images/myimage.jpg" /></p>
```

But when I add that block to a column, it shows nothing. If I check the option to show the block title, it shows the block title, but no image.

Any help on that? I have searched for any issues like mine, but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suppose that you need to choose "FULL HTML" format for your block content.

Comment: I have already used it, but nothing. Thanks for the tip, anyway.

Comment: I will add a comment to say that I don't know how I did it, but putting Full HTML it worked. I thought I had tried it, but it seems that is not true. Thanks!